# Is there a Google Chrome extension that can show JS being executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

When I hover over some visual element on a page it's get resized. I know that this is done via `jQuery` and actual code responsible for this is on
lines 815-820 in `application.js` file.

But to knew this I spent 5 minutes analyzing and debugging JS.
It would be awesome, if I just hover over this element and I get a popup (`application.js:815`)

Is there any solutions for my problem? Or maybe there are simpler ways to know which parts of JS responsible for which user interactions?

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome Dev tools -> Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints and/or Profiles -> Collect JavaScript CPU Profile ?

Comment: Thanks Rob! Didn't know about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a better tool for interacting with JS code than the integrated Developer Tools. What you could do to help debug code that interacts with the DOM is to set DOM breakpoints:

On the **Elements tab**, right click an element and select **Break on...** and in your case it should be **Attributes modifications**. Now each time JS code changes an attribute of that element, it should break and allow you to easily debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this just by "googling" a little bit, there is already a debugger in Google Chrome

[Here's a link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)